# Installing Ubuntu 64 bit on Mac using VMWare Fusion 3 Display Issue

Tags: macos, ubuntu, gnome, display, vmware-fusion

I have installed Ubuntu 64 bit on a 2009 Mac Book Pro running Snow Leopard using VMWare Fusion 3.  When I start the vm and reach the login screen I enter my user name and password and the progress bar moves for a bit then the machine goes back to the login prompt.  If I try selecting Failsafe GNOME from the list I can get it - although at the low display resolution.  If I then run vmware-user the screen adjusts itself correctly to the right resolution.  I do have the VMWare Tools installed and I have restarted the machine a number of times.  For some reason I am having trouble finding the xorg.conf file on the machine also. It does not seem to be at the usual location and does not show up in a locate.  I would like to just be able to login to GNOME proper.  Does anyone have an idea about what is going on?  Also, I should mention that I run Snow Leopard in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Provide the Ubuntu version, as 9.10 is “not yet supported” (since it was released *after* VMware 3.0).

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to give the Ubuntu version - it is 9.10.  I guess I will wait for support from VMWare and just use the previous version of Ubuntu for now.

Comment: With Fusion 3.0.1, Ubuntu 9.10 is supported. Works well on my computer. Fixed this display problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced to the same problem, then I login into xterm session, and then

```
rm -rf ~/.config/gnome-session
```

And logout, then it's ok to login to gnome again

Comment: Thanks very much - this worked for me.  I even tried again from scratch before I saw your response and it still did not work.  I happened to need to reformat Snow Leopard and I installed the latest version of VMWare from the start and still had the same problem.  However, your suggestion solved the problem.